# Updating colorbox with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, colorbox

I am very new to using AJAX, basically this is my first project, and i'm kinda clueless to what the best way to approach this would be.

The scenario and what i want to accomplish.
Currently i'm opening a form with a select list, in the "lightbox" plugin colorbox. 
Now with one of the options form the select list i need to redirect the client to a form with a textbox and from there execute my php.

Basically this is what i wish to accomplish:

- Load all the content inside the same colorbox frame.
- Redirect clients to a textbox form.
- Return the result of the php code i've executed after the forms has been submitted.

I would really appreciate if a kind soul could guide me in the right direction, to what i have to do to make this work.

Comment: You don't need to redirect clients to a textbox form. you can load textarea inside colorbox, enter text and post with ajax. Do you use jQuery?? http://api.jquery.com/load/ : load textarea in to wrapper. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ : post your data and get result without page reload :)

Comment: How exactly would this be done? i.e: the textbox should only appear after the select form has been submitted.

Comment: add button and wrapper to your colorbox -> onclick load textbox and submit button in to wrapper -> after filling textbox with text click the submit button and get result in to the wrapper instead of textbox :) All functions and code snippets are documented in jQuery book.